# How to convert date-time "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss" that's stored in a String to a Date object?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, date, datetime

I want to insert into a Mysql column (DATETIME  column) a time & date . For that purpose i use 
the DATETIME field .

But on the JAVA side , I need to have a Date object with the time & date .

Consider the code :

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    String str = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
    System.out.println(str);
```

This code produces :

```
2014/03/19 01:11:35
```

How can I convert it to a Date object in the format `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss`  , so it would be 
possible to put it in the mysql column of DATETIME  ?

Much appreciated

Comment: The short answer is, don't.  If the database is expecting a `DATETIME` value then you should be using `java.sql.Date`, for example, `new java.sql.Date(cal.getTime().getTime())` or `new java.sql.Date(cal.getTimeInMillis())`

Comment: There should be *no reason* to create a *string* to pass to MySQL. Use parameterized queries and let the database adapter map the type (a Date, perhaps) as appropriate.

Comment: Take a look at [Java, JDBC and MySQL Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html) for details about mappings between database types and Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `getTime()` method of Calendar returns a Date object.

For JDBC, you'll use a `java.sql.Timestamp` to preserve the time component. (I think a `java.sql.Date` loses the time component.)

For example:

```
 preparedStatement.setTimestamp(new java.sql.Timestamp(cal.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 2):

First point: `Date` objects have no "format" - they just represent an instant in time.
If you print them, you get the default `toString()` implementation for `Date`.

Second point: You don't need to format a `Date` to use it with JDBC.
You should use a prepared statement, then call `setObject()`, to set the parameter value - the JDBC driver will do the rest, including wrapping in quotes if that's required for the data type.

Final point: Never use `Calendar` unless you *have* to.
In this case, simply `new Date()` will do the job.